# How to add comparison value in tooltip of Highchart Stock without changing Yaxis scale

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have a chart and I need the time navigator like in Highchart Stocks so I've used Stock with some hand made options and it render really nicely.
In stocks you have the option to plot the variation instead of the values.
For exemple with this data serie :

[1,2,3,4,5] the variations are [+1,+1,+1,+1]. You can access this information in the tooltip with {point.change} and the serie plotoption {compare:'value'}.

But doing so changes the YAxis to fit these variations.
I only want to show the variation in the tooltip and not change my chart. any idea?

This is the correct chart **with correct YAxis** but you can see the tooltip never show the variation:
http://jsfiddle.net/techunter/PhW3t/

This one with {compare: 'percent'} shows the right variation in the tooltip but **wrong YAxis scale**:
http://jsfiddle.net/techunter/PhW3t/49/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it's really hard to get it working so I've made my tooltip formatter like this :

```
tooltip: {
                formatter:function(a,b,c){
                    var s = '<b>'+ Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %e, %Y', this.x) +'</b>';
                    $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {
                        var prev = jQuery.inArray(point.x, point.series.processedXData)-1;
                        if(prev>=0){
                            prev = point.series.points[prev];
                            var percent = (point.y - prev.y) *100 / point.y;
                            var positive = false;
                            if(percent>0){
                                positive = true;
                                percent='+'+percent;
                            }
                            else
                                percent = percent +'';
                            percent = percent.substring(0,percent.indexOf('.')+3)+'%';
                            if(positive)
                                percent = '<span style="color:#000000">'+percent+'</span>';
                            else
                                percent = '<span style="color:#FF0000">'+percent+'</span>';
                            s += '<br/>'+'<span style="color:'+point.series.color+'">'+point.series.name+'</span>: <b>'+point.y+'</b> ('+percent+')';
                        }
                        else{
                            s += '<br/>'+'<span style="color:'+point.series.color+'">'+point.series.name+'</span>: <b>'+point.y+'</b>';
                        }
                    });

                    return s;
                },
                enable:true
            },
```

In action:
http://jsfiddle.net/techunter/PhW3t/55/

If anyone has a better/faster idea please share.

Comment: Why can't you pull this difference down in your dataset itself? See my answer edit for idea on how to accomplish this.

Comment: my dataset is for demonstration purpose so I've made the set by hand. Precalculation is not possible in my case or it's almost the same of what i've done here

Answer (score -1):

Looking at your code you are setting the min/max of the yAxis to 2/5 respectively - which is the same as your non-variation chart.
Try [these](http://jsfiddle.net/7Kzvk/) values (lets you see all points):

```
yAxis: {
            min: -10,
            max:25,
            title: {
                text: '# of Hospitalizations'
            }
        }
```

You can set the min/max by the calculated values if you want as well.

**EDIT:**
I found this [link](http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=18320) which describes doing pre-calculations and putting that data in the series object as a note field. If you are returning your data from a SQL call this should be easy. A simple modification of your SQL to return a new column with the percentage change. Then, call the percentage change from a call to the note field.

Comment: I want YAxis to always display the number of hospitalizations which only varies between an average of 2 and 5 per clinic. the values you get in your graph is the variations that's why you reach -10 because it's a percentage which I try to avoid here

Comment: Ahh, sorry, it was hard to tell from the question (or it is too early). You want percentage shown in tooltip but values shown in series. If you can determine the algorithm used to get percentages you can roll your own tooltip calculator.

Comment: I don't want to do this by hand. Or it's just : (current-prev)/current*100 but I don't know how to access the data from inside the formatter